# Ehcache 0B of physical memory when using containerd

Tags: jvm, containerd

We have a docker image that works when run via docker in local or via docker runtime in a kubernetes cluster. It throws error when run in containerd

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to allocate 50.0MB of
> memory when the host only contains 0B of physical memory

ehcache version: 3.9.3

containerd version: 1.3.7

os: rhel 7

framework: springboot

packaging: gradle

Answer (score 1):

Use latest JDK 11 like: openjdk:11.0.13 will fix your issue without using JVM flag: -XX:-UseContainerSupport

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this might be a possible bug using containerd as observe also here https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/2934

The solution was to disable ContainerSupport of JVM via `-XX:-UseContainerSupport`